# Loop in R with big data set, a better way?

Tags: r, loops, csv, rstudio

Dear Stack Overflow'ers,

Currently i have a data set of 33 columns with 1447499 rows.

Now I want to add 1 new column with new data (Unix timestamp based on a date that is in the 33rd column)

I've created the first timestamp manually and then has to add 5 (ms) every time to the timestamp, is the code below usefull?

What i did so far:

```
# Data loading is fine
PhoneSensorData$UnixTimestamp <- 0
lengte = nrow(PhoneSensorData)
PhoneSensorData$UnixTimestamp[1] = 1496944482155

for (i in 1:lengte) {
  PhoneSensorData$UnixTimestamp[i] = 1496944482155 + (5*i)
}
```

But this runs for ages (or has not finished for almost an hour now)
Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way?

And after that, i have to export it back to a csv again. 
Loading of the data takes me about 10-15 sec with fread, so that is fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be way faster, thanks to vectorization:

```
PhoneSensorData$UnixTimestamp = 1496944482155 + (5*(1:lengte))
```

With saving you can't speed things up very much, since you add a column and so have to rewrite every line of the file. The bottleneck here is the filesystem.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much, saved me ALOT of time :)

Answer (score 1):

In R, you shouldn't use for loops to create / edit a new column.
They're vector based operations and R is really good at vector based operations.

With data.table, you can do it with these codes:

```
library(data.table)
PhoneSensorData <- data.table(PhoneSensorData)
PhoneSensorData[, RowNumber := 1:.N]
PhoneSensorData[, UnixTimeStamp := 1496944482155  + RowNumber * 5 ]
fwrite(PhoneSensorData, file="PhoneSensorData.csv")
```

PS: data.table's fwrite function is also really fast. I recommend you to use it.

Comment: You could use `.I` instead of generating `RowNumber`, saves Memory and probably a little bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

To create regular sequences of data (no matter whether of strings, numbers, or dates and times) you can use the standard R `seq` function.

In your case it specifying the arguments `from`, `by` and `length.out` is the most convenient way to achieve your goal:

```
PhoneSensorData$UnixTimestamp <- 
            seq(from = 1496944482155, by = 5, length.out = nrow(PhoneSensorData))
```

Comment: Try to provide more detailed well formatted answer.